# What is the lifespan of string literals in C?

Tags: c

What is the lifespan of the string literals `"zero"` and `"non-zero"` in the following program?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* tester(int inp)
{
    const char *retval=NULL;

    if (inp==0)
        retval="zero";
    else
        retval="non-zero";

    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    const char *outval=NULL;

    outval=tester(0);
    printf("0 is %s\n",outval);
    outval=tester(1);
    printf("1 is %s\n",outval);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I know from [this question in the C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html) that `"zero"` and `"non-zero"` are (or at least are allowed to be) read-only.  I assume that is why I had to put in the `const`s before the `char*` declarations to stop the compiler's warnings about "... discards 'const' qualifier ...".  But while the program gives the expected result of

> 0 is zero
>
> 1 is non-zero

I also know that `tester` can not be defined as:

```
char* tester(int inp)
{
    char retval[9];

    if (inp==0)
        strcpy(retval,"zero");
    else
        strcpy(retval,"non-zero");

    return retval;
}
```

because the array `retval` must be assumed to be disposed of when `tester` exits.

So can I do what I have done in the original code or must I use `malloc`?

Comment: `const` does not imply read-only. C has no symbolic constants other than `enum`-constants.

Comment: copying your constant in an auto-variable shortens its life if you use the return variable! assign to a pointer works.

Answer (score 1):

String literals have static storage duration (i.e. their lifetime is the execution time of the program).

See [§6.4.5/6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) of the C standard.

Comment: [Where is it?](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p5)

Comment: @eugene: fixed the typo (it's in para 6) and added the link. Thanks for the html.